# Tensor product IBM on Quantum Experience

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

How can you take the Tensor Product in IBM Quantum Experience?
For example
$$(X|1⟩) \otimes ((X|1⟩)$$

I have tried to look up but couldn’t find anything

Answer (score 1):

Lets have two general single qubit gates $A$ and $B$. If you apply $A$ on first qubit and $B$ on second qubit, you will get two qubit gate $A \otimes B$. In your case $A = B = X$.

Just note that $X|1\rangle \otimes X|1\rangle = |0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$.

Here is an example of tensor product $S \otimes T$ implementation:

[image]

As tensor product is not commutative operation, $T \otimes S$ is implemented followingly:

[image]